# Removing node when subnode meet a specific conditon

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to remove node from an xml file when the subnode "number" equals 0. Here what is look like.

```
<deFac xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="baba_002.xsd">
  <fact>
    <refact>163620515-01</refact>
    <date>2016-09-06</date>
    <demfact>
      <number>0</number>
      <brut>81.46</brut>
      <net>81.46</net>
    </demfact>
   </fact>
  <fact>
    <refact>163621197-02</refact>
    <date>2016-09-06</date>
    <demfact>
      <number>11</number>
      <brut>61.44</brut>
      <net>61.44</net>
    </demfact>
  </fact>
  <fact>
    <refact>163621203-01</refact>
    <date>2016-09-06</date>
    <demfact>
      <number>1</number>
      <brut>4.55</brut>
      <net>4.55</net>
    </demfact>
  </fact>
  <fact>
    <refact>163621198-01</refact>
    <date>2016-09-06</date>
    <demfact>
      <number>0</number>
      <brut>1.71</brut>
      <net>1.71</net>
    </demfact>
  </fact>
</deFac>
```

What I want is that

```
<deFac xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="baba_002.xsd">
  <fact>
    <refact>163621197-02</refact>
    <date>2016-09-06</date>
    <demfact>
      <number>11</number>
      <brut>61.44</brut>
      <net>61.44</net>
    </demfact>
  </fact>
  <fact>
    <refact>163621203-01</refact>
    <date>2016-09-06</date>
    <demfact>
      <number>1</number>
      <brut>4.55</brut>
      <net>4.55</net>
    </demfact>
  </fact>
</deFac>
```

This the xslt that I tried but it's not giving me the results that I wanted

First try:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="fact[number = !0]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Second try

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="deFac/fact"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="deFac/fact/[demfact/number != '0']">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Do you know where I made my mistake ? I'm really blocked and everything I tried seems to not work as excpected.

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first attempt, change `<xsl:template match="fact[number = !0]"/>` to `<xsl:template match="fact[demfact/number = 0]"/>`.